# Download Webpage with HTTrack executed JavaScript

Tags: javascript, download, html, httrack

I want to save a webpage with httrack including the executed JavaScript-Output. I'm using:

```
httrack -r1 URL -O PATH
```

Currently I'm only getting the .js-source:

```
"<script src="...js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there any option I can add to the httrack-command that will execute the javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "execute the javascript", because Httrack doesn't actually do that, maybe you should try using a Webkit like the one below
http://phantomjs.org

Comment: Instead of phantomjs, in this day and age you're better off using headless Chrome.

Comment: For example:

If I'm mirroring the page "https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css-js/html-css-js-intro/a/review-javascript" with HTTrack the Questions-Section is not part of the output.

But if I'm saving the page with Firefox (File -> Save Page As...) the complete page is being downloaded.

Is it possbile to do this process in HTTrack?

Comment: Can anyone give me an advice?

Comment: No reply anymore?